# how to get day of week from date in apache drill sql?

Tags: sql, apache-drill, datepart, dbeaver, sql-date-functions

I am using dbeaver connected to apache drill sql , trying to get day of week.

For example for `'1/27/2019'` the day of week is `1`, considering sunday as the first day of week.

Example 2 : `'1/28/2019'`, output : `2`

Answer (score 1):

In Apache Drill SQL, you should be able to use [the `TO_CHAR()` data type conversion method](https://drill.apache.org/docs/data-type-conversion/#to_char). Format specifier `'e'` should be what you need :

```
TO_CHAR(my_date_col, 'e')
```

If your dates are stored as string, you would need to convert them to date first, for example using `TO_DATE` :

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(my_string_col, , 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'e')
```

Comment: Thank you ,its working , is there any way to mention start day of the week in TO_CHAR.     select to_char(current_timestamp,'e') its returning 7 as sunday is the last day of the week. how can we get the value as 1 stating that sunday is the start day of the week

Comment: @Surya I don't think there is a standard option for that, and I cannot find it in the documentation.

Comment: You would have to roll up your own logic, like, for example : `CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(my_date_col, 'e') = 1 
    THEN '7' 
    ELSE TO_CHAR( TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR(my_date_col, 'e'), '#' ) + 1, '#' ) 
END`

Answer (score 0):

TO_CHAR(date_col, 'e') will return number. For example, if the weekday on Monday, it will return 1. and so on...

TO_CHAR(date_col, 'E') will return characters. For example, if the weekday on Monday, it will return Mon. and so on...

Make sure your date column is in date format, if not first convert it to date format using TO_DATE() and then perform the above step.